How to deal with unconstrained widgets in a row in Flutter
I cannot understand how this make sense, or to me it does not make any sense. I have this code:
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: TapRegion(
        onTapOutside: (event) => _searchFocusNode.unfocus(),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          width: _isFocused
              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80
              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: TextField(
            controller: _searchController,
            focusNode: _searchFocusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
              filled: true,
              hintText: 'Search',
              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 12.0),
            ),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
            onSubmitted: (value) {
              _search(false);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Visibility(
      visible: _isFocused,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _searchFocusNode.unfocus();
          _searchController.clear();
          setState(() {
            _isFocused = false;
          });
        },
        child: const Text(
          'Cancel',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),

The search field takes the whole Row, but when pressed, it shrinks to let a button appear to the right of it. This works well. I have no issues with it. However, in the widget inspector, it say that the width of the Visibility is unconstrained. All my attempts of making it constrained have only resulted in the search bar not taking up the full width.

Is there any way to solve this?
Is the widget inspector unconstrained warnings even something to bother about? My app works well on multiple different devices, however before launch I want to get rid of all warnings, just in case someone has some weird device that causes issues. But considering how much trouble I have dealing with this, and basically solving nothing that is visible on any normal phone I have tried, should I even bother with this?


Hi, Without the whole code is difficult to provide a clear solution.   I would try: *Using Flexible instead of Expanded can provide more consistent behavior when altering width with layout-affecting widgets like Visibility.   *Adjust the AnimatedContainer. Using MediaQuery.of(context).Size.width can cause problems while scaling. Instead, try to use SizedBox.Expand() to force the container to fill the available space and then change the size based on the status.
